# How select objects from model in Yii depends on relational table

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

im new with Yii and confused about AR relations
For example i has two tables with MANY_MANY relation

```
CREATE TABLE `banner` (
  `banner_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `banner_action` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`banner_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `position` (
  `position_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `position_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`position_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `banner_position` (
  `banner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `position_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`banner_id`,`position_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Banner can be in one or more positions, for example banner with id 1 can be placed at positions 1 and 2 and banner 2 can be placed at 2 and 3
Now i want to grab all banners for position 2, expected i get both banners now
Also i want to check banner field  and if it empty or 'test' then get this banner

In simple life without ORM id like these SQL

```
SELECT b.banner_id FROM banner b
INNER JOIN banner_position bp ON bp.banner_id = b.banner_id AND bp.position_id = 2
WHERE (b.banner_action = 'test' OR b.banner_action IS NULL)
```

In Yii i cant understand how to be

I wrote criteria for banner_action

```
$select = new CDbCriteria;
$select->addCondition(array('banner_action = "test" OR banner_action IS NULL'));
```

And use model to get results

```
$banner = BannerModel::model()->find($select);
```

How i can now add position criteria, should i use $model->with(???) or just add JOIN into criteria?

```
$select->join = 'INNER JOIN banner_position bp ON bp.position_id = 2 AND bp.banner_id = t.banner_id';
```

Also i use correlation name `t` in JOIN because its defaults for SQL building, is this right, or i need to use method to get right correlation name in case it have been changed in some situations?

I also try relation way

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'positions' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'PositionModel',
            'banner_position(banner_id, position_id)')
    );
}
```

And this select (i has no idea how add criteria like banner_action='test' or banner_action is null anyway)

```
$banner = BannerModel::model()
                ->with('positions')
                ->find('positions.position_id = 2');
```

And Yii build SQL not looks like i expected (i need INNER JOIN and i dont need `positions` table join only banner_positions (this is conditional select))
and seems that criteria with join is only way to get simple and clean sql that i need
And i get models in result set anyway... maybe there is no way in Yii to handle conditional relations?

```
SELECT `t`.`banner_id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`banner_type` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`banner_content` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`banner_target` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`banner_controller` AS `t0_c4`, `t`.`banner_action` AS `t0_c5`, `t`.`banner_param_type` AS `t0_c6`, `t`.`banner_param_direction` AS `t0_c7`, `t`.`banner_param_kind` AS `t0_c8`, `positions`.`position_id` AS `t1_c0`, `positions`.`position_name` AS `t1_c1` FROM `banner` 
`t`  LEFT OUTER JOIN `banner_position` `positions_positions` ON (`t`.`banner_id`=`positions_positions`.`banner_id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `position` `positions` ON (`positions`.`position_id`=`positions_positions`.`position_id`)  
WHERE (positions.position_id = 2)
```

Comment: did u tried [`MANY_MANY`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr) relation supported by yii?

Comment: @dInGd0nG i changed question adds additional info, please check it

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged this question active record you should be using [relational Active Records](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr).

You have to define a relation between your tables in your models:

for example for `Banner`

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'positions'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Position',
            'banner_position(banner_id, position_id)'),
    );
}
```

and then it will create an array of all the positions in your `Banner` model.

Comment: I changed question to handle your idea, please check new text if you interested in it